# Powershell script for backing up files does not work

Tags: powershell, path, backup

I've created this simple script using powershell that prompts the user for the location of three folders. Once they input the paths for these folders the script should copy what is in the first one, 'theFolder' into the second, 'theStaging' and then finally, into the third 'backup' but for some reason, this does not work?

Instead it turns the last folder into a file named backup. Does anyone know why? Your help would be very much appreciated.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$theFolder = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter folder location you wish to backup"
$staging = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter staging folder location"
$backup = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter backup location"

Remove-Item $backup -Recurse -Force
Copy-Item -Path $theFolder\* -Destination $staging -Recurse -Force
Copy-Item -Path $staging\* -Destination $backup -Recurse -Force
Remove-Item $staging\* -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/copy-item-creating-file-instead-of-folder/)

Comment: Use `Test-Path` to see if a destination folder exists and if not use `New-Item` to create it first. What I don't understand here is why you are not copying to the backup folder straight away since you're removing everything from staging almost directly after copying to it.. Also: User input should ALWAYS be checked first so what you are doing here is asking for trouble if you ask me..

Comment: @JeroenHeier Nothing is answered within that post.

Comment: step through your code in a debugger like ISE or VSCode and test it.  you can also run each command on your own and test it works as expected.

Comment: If you are getting a file that means the destination folder does not exist. Check your $backup variable

Comment: Still not convinced? By `Remove-Item $backup` you delete the backup folder, but later on you expect it to be there to receive the files...